# MySQL search for a record having AND NOT having specific tags

Tags: mysql, tags

In a large project (collection of solved problems in …) I have a data organized like this (a typical M:N relation):

```
records | record_id, other_info
tag_map | map_id, record_id, tag_id
tags    | tag_id, tag_text, other info
```

I would like to add filtering feature. In the filter the user can choose for each tag whether its presence is required, ignored or forbidden.

e.g. I need to find all records that

- have tag with tag_id = 1
- AND have tag with tag_id = 4
- AND do not have tag with tag_id = 3
- and any other tags are not important.

Comment: `have tag with tag_id = 1 AND have tag with tag_id = 4` ... obviously this is not possible.  Did you mean OR?

Comment: It is possible - imagine books and their tags: fiction, adventure, document, hasImages, wasFilmed. Now I want to get all books that have images AND were filmed AND are not fiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `(record_id,tag_id)` tuple is unique in the `tag_map` table, we could use a combination of join and anti-join operations.

For example:

```
 SELECT r.record_id
   FROM records r

   JOIN tag_map t1 
     ON t1.record_id = r.record_id
    AND t1.tag_id    = 1  

   JOIN tag_map t4
     ON t4.record_id = r.record_id
    AND t4.tag_id    = 4

   LEFT
   JOIN tag_map t3
     ON t3.record_id = r.record_id
    AND t3.tag_id    = 3

  WHERE t3.record_id IS NULL
```

Again, this is based on the existence of a uniqueness constraint on `(record_id,tag_id)` in `tag_map` table. Otherwise, this has the potential to return "duplicate" rows.

There are other query patterns that can return equivalent results. For example, we could use a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` in place of the anti-join.

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query:

```
SELECT records.record_id, records.otherinfo FROM records, tags, tag_map
WHERE records.record_id = tagmap.record_id AND tags.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id 
AND tags.tag_id = 1 AND tags.tag_id = 4 AND <> 3
```

Comment: This would still return `records` that are associated with a `tag_id` of `3`. And it returns rows that are associated with `tag_id` 1 or 4. The specification was that the record should be associated with *both* 1 and 4, and not associated with 3. (Is there some reason we are *still* using the old school comma syntax for join operations?)